# HTTP Error 500.21

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm setting up an MVC site on a new live server.  On other non-live servers it worked but on live I get this error

```
HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error

Handler "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list
```

I have installed MVC 3 and MVC 4 but I still get this error.  I restarted the site in IIS and restarted the server but nothing is working.  Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your application pool to use integrated mode instead of classic mode. (or was is the other way around?)

Comment: I have this already - it is alraady integrated as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Can be also that you are missing right version of .NET installed on your server.

Run

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

This should help you, just remember to run Command Prompt as Administrator.